# Why in this case I can not use "where" instead of "left join on"?

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL. And I am practicing SQL questions on leetcode.

This is the question: https://leetcode.com/problems/combine-two-tables/

Why can't I use:

```
select Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Address.City, Address.State
from Person,Address
where Address.PersonId=Person.PersonId
```

It failed in this case:

```
Input:
{"headers": {"Person": ["PersonId", "LastName", "FirstName"], "Address": ["AddressId", "PersonId", "City", "State"]}, "rows": {"Person": [[1, "Wang", "Allen"]], "Address": []}}
Output:
{"headers": ["FirstName", "LastName", "City", "State"], "values": []}
Expected:
{"headers": ["FirstName", "LastName", "City", "State"], "values": [["Allen", "Wang", null, null]]}
```

The accepted answer is:

```
select Person.Firstname, Person.lastname, Address.city, Address.state
from Person
left join Address on Person.PersonId = Address.PersonId
```

Why is this? I thought both of the queries would accomplish the same thing and have the same effect.

Comment: The where clause creates an implicit _inner join_, not a _left join_. They are not the same. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: THX, I've read that topic. It explained this question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the below reson.

[image]

While --> where clause creates an implicit inner join

[image]

Comment: Unless you created them, please supply attribution for the images.

Answer (score 2):

The question states

> Write a SQL query for a report that provides the following information
>   for each person in the Person table, regardless if there is an address
>   for each of those people:

Notice the last part says regardless if there is an address. So if you use a `WHERE` clause you will not be getting results for entries that do not contain an address. On the other hand, <s>a join</s> a *left join* will combine both tables despite whether or not there is an entry in the `Address` table for a given `Person`.

Comment: _On the other hand, a join will combine both tables_ should be stated as _On the other hand, a **LEFT** join will combine both tables_

Comment: I felt like a complete dingus after reading this; so obvious. Thank you kindly stranger!